# how to transform output SVM into probability using 'Platt scaling' method?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I worked on the problem of  handwritten recognition  images. For this, I use support vector machines  as a classifier .  the matrix score shows an example of the scores returned by svm for 5 samples. the number of classes is also 5. I want to transform this matrix into probabilities.

```
 score=[ 0,2590 -0,6033 -1,1350 -1,2347 -0,9776
      -1,4727   -0,2136 -0,9649  0,1480 -1,4761
      -0,9637   -0,8662  0,0674 -1,0051 -1,1293
      -2,1230   -0,8805 -0,9808 -0,0520 -0,0836
      -1,6976   -1,1578 -0,9205 -1,1101  1,0796]
```

According to research on existing methods, I found that the Platt's scaling method is most appropriate in my case. I found an implementation of this method on this link [Platt scaling](https://github.com/sergeyk/vislab/blob/master/matlab/hedging-1.0/learn_platt_params.m) but the problem is that I don't understand the third parameter to enter. Please, help me to understand this implementation and to make it executable

I await your answers and thank you in advance

Comment: Is this the output of `svmclassify`? shouldn't it be `[5x1]` matrix?

Comment: this is the output for svm multicalss (ona against all)

Comment: You're right, so you are probably working with `libsvm` package, which I'm not familiar with, sorry!

Comment: `Platt scaling` is your keyword ;)

Comment: I used this toolbox http://asi.insa-rouen.fr/enseignants/~arakoto/toolbox/  to do classification. already, I tried with libsvm but it gives an accuracy rate lower than this toolbox. I found libsvm  50% accuracy while 70% with the other toolbox that's why I need another method to find the probability

Comment: @Thomas Jungblut  thank you for your answer, do you know any implementation of this method in matlab ???

Comment: If you are using LIBSVM then `svmpredict` gives the probability directly. You don't have to do anything. Also, it is highly unlikely that two different toolboxes for SVM will give two different results.

Comment: @Parag S. Chandakkar yes when I use libsvm, the result is lower and you can see in this link the program that I was used http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30399223/how-can-perform-accuracy-using-libsvm-for-matlab. there is any mistake??

Comment: See Platt, John (1999). "Probabilistic outputs for support vector machines and comparisons to regularized likelihood methods". Advances in large margin classifiers 10 (3): 61–74.